# Dartlang: How to detect that the client is closing

Tags: html, dart

I need to be able to detect that the HTTP client page is closing so I may tell the server that it should do some clean up.  Is it possible to do this?

Comment: This detailed example of how to detect closing http://stackoverflow.com/q/23975652/75062 was great help!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the BeforeUnload event to detect when a user navigates away from the page:

```dart
window.onBeforeUnload.listen((e) {
  // Do what you need to do
});
```

Note that this will detect any navigation away from the page, not just closing, which I assume is your desired behaviour.

Comment: The page will control a camera in an aircraft so I may need to stop storing images if the client is not being used.  I have not got your code to work yet but see the next comment.

Answer (score 3):

There is no guarantee that the script at the client side will be executed correctly, because user can lose connection, browser can crash and so on. If it is a critical task(cleaning) then in addition to the client side solution you also should use some sort of a timeout.

Comment: I do want to know if the browser crashes or the client closes.  I have a heartbeat timer running on the client, sending a message to the server via a web socket and I can trap that message.  I think I need another timer to detect if the heartbeat stops.  BTW this is my first web page and I'm new art Dart as well ...