# Dart How is the websocket pingInterval actually used?

Tags: websocket, dart

I have been testing using a web-socket and want to use pingInterval to determine if the client has closed but I have been unable to detect that.  I send a message over the websocket every 4 seconds.  When I quit the browser no error condition is generated, I think, and I have not been able to figure out how to detect that the web-socket closed the connection.  How can I detect that?  I'm new at Dart and web applications as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tested it with SDK 1.5.0.dev:

**Server code:**

```dart
import 'dart:io';
main() {
  HttpServer.bind('127.0.0.1', 4040).then((server) {
    server.listen((HttpRequest request) {
      WebSocketTransformer.upgrade(request).then((socket) {
        socket.listen((msg){
          socket.pingInterval = new Duration(seconds : 1);
          print('server received message: $msg');
          socket.add('server received message: $msg');
        });
        socket.done.then((e){
            print("WebSocket closed with:"
                  "socket.closeReason: ${socket.closeReason}, "
                  "socket.closeCode: ${socket.closeCode}");
          });
      });
    });
  });
}
```

**Client code:**

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:async';
void main() {
  querySelector('button').onClick.first.then((e){
    for (int i = 0; i > -1; i++){
      print("epic code");
    }
  });
  WebSocket ws = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:4040');
  ws.onMessage.listen((MessageEvent e) {
    querySelector('#response').appendHtml('<p>${e.data}</p>');
  });
  Timer t = new Timer.periodic(new Duration(seconds : 1), (t) {
    ws.sendString('timer fired');
  });
}
```

**html:**

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ClientTest</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="clienttest.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <button type="button">Hang</button>
    <p>Response:</p>

    <div id="response">
    </div>

    <script type="application/dart" src="clienttest.dart"></script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

For Example, if you close browser window then client-server will close socket with `socket.closeReason: , socket.closeCode: 1005` of course you can provide your own reason if it wasn't "sudden death"  [CloseEvent codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CloseEvent)

But if you set `pingInterval` and press `Hang` button then server will close socket on timeout but with `socket.closeReason: null, socket.closeCode: null`. Without `pingInterval` it will keep waiting.

Probably, Dart team should provide something more 'exhaustive' than `null`. But you can ping it yourself with [Stream timeout](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-async.Stream)

```dart
Stream timeout(Duration timeLimit, {Function void onTimeout(EventSink sink)})
```

> Creates a new stream with the same events as this stream.
>
> Whenever more than timeLimit passes between two events from this
>   stream, the onTimeout function is called.
>
> The countdown doesn't start until the returned stream is listened to.
>   The countdown is reset every time an event is forwarded from this
>   stream, or when the stream is paused and resumed.
>
> The onTimeout function is called with one argument: an EventSink that
>   allows putting events into the returned stream. This EventSink is only
>   valid during the call to onTimeout.
>
> If onTimeout is omitted, a timeout will just put a TimeoutException
>   into the error channel of the returned stream.
>
> The returned stream is not a broadcast stream, even if this stream is.

Comment: Since I'm new at this it took me a bit of time to fiddle with the code to better understand it and much, much, less time to implement it in my code and test it.  I note that the socket.closeReason returns null with the code 1005 and that when I migrate to a new tab in safari in IOS (iPad) no close or anything else is returned - which is what I want. Hooray!